# deleting selected items with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I delete multiple selected items by using button delete? Below is example from jQuery API for selecting more items. I just added the button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
            e.metaKey = true;
        }).selectable({
            stop: function() {
                var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                    var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                    result.append( "Selected items: " + ( index + 1 ) );
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<p id="feedback">
    <span>Selected items:</span> 
</p>
<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete"">
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're marking things as selected, but something like this might work:

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    $('.ui-selected').hide(); //assuming selected items have class ui-selected
};
```

Comment: In your original post, before the edit, you forgot to add the `#` in front of the delete in your selector.

Comment: How does it make change?

Comment: `$('#delete')` selects the element with `id="delete"` (which is how you should select your delete button), `$('delete')` selects the non-existent `<delete>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove` to completely remove the `selected` element like following.

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
   $('.ui-selected').remove(); 
});
```